# my couchdb maybe barken, how can I repair it?

Tags: couchdb, restart

all,
 I met a very serious problem about my couchdb. I install the couchdb on a virtual machine, the system is ubuntu. The disk of this ubuntu is 10G, I asked the couchdb to catch data from twitter but I was not aware that the couchdb occupy all the disk storage in the system. To get some storage to run the couchdb, I have delete the system log. Then I type: sudo service couchdb start, it is start, but the http://127.0.0.1:9000/_utils/cannot open. All show in the following. Is anyone can help?? I am really anxious, because all my data is store only in this couchdb.

---

- Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
  ubuntu@election2:~$ sudo service couchdb status
  couchdb stop/waiting
  ubuntu@election2:~$ sudo service couchdb start
  couchdb start/running, process 1325
  ubuntu@election2:~$ sudo service couchdb status
  couchdb stop/waiting
  ubuntu@election2:~$ sudo service couchdb stop
  stop: Unknown instance: 
  ubuntu@election2:~$ sudo service couchdb restart
  stop: Unknown instance: 
  couchdb start/running, process 1601
  ubuntu@election2:~$

  ---

if this couchdb is difficult to repair, is anyone can tell me how can I remove the data in this couchdb wihtout starting it.There must be some tangible document. Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 2):

There are two CouchDB configuration files, `default.ini` and `local.ini`.  My `default.ini` contains an entry in the `[couchdb]` section called `database_dir` which  specifies where couch databases are stored.  To find your configuration files run: `couchdb -c`.  Your database .couch file will have the same name as you would have seen in the web interface.  To remove the database, delete the file.  If you want to keep the data, move it to a different location.

Shut down couch using: `couchdb -d` or `sudo service couchdb stop` depending on how you started it.

Once shut down you can copy / move the couchdb database directory to a location with more space.  Change your `database_dir` setting to the new location and restart couchdb with: `couchdb -b` or `sudo service couchdb start`

Answer (score 1):

The data is stored as a db file with the name of the CouchDB bucket in a dictionary that is specified in the local.ini as database_dir. Delete the file and the data is gone.

The running CouchDB can be killed by `kill :pid`. The `:pid` is a number (process id) and can be investigated with the command `ps -ax | grep "couchdb"`